# SharePoint list won't save attachments

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, error, attachments

SharePoint newbie here. I have created an out-of-the-box list (with no custom code) and have been happily using it. This morning when I went to create my 16th list entry, it would not allow me to save the attachment (everything else in the entry saves, just not the attachment).

It allows me to upload the attachment and hit "save." However, when I open the entry, the attachment is gone/never actually saved. This is true for both new and existing list entries.

I restarted the browser, tried different browsers, restarted my machine, tried different types of attachments, etc. I checked the list settings - attachments are enabled.

I am having the same issue as this [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/178498/sharepoint-2013-wont-save-attachments-added-in-edit-screen?rq=1) but with the exception that my list has no customization.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After uploading the attachment, whether you can view the attachment column display as below:

[image]

After saving this list entry and View Item, if you can view the Attachments column?

Try to disable and re-enable the Attachment option in the advanced settings.

Check if you can view the attachment in another list.

Comment: Thank you very much! Oddly enough it is working fine now. I disabled and re-enabled the attachment option (though I tried it a few days ago to no avail), and now it works just fine. Magic! Thanks again